# Can't create new project in Angular 6 after updating angular cli to 6.0.0

Tags: angular6

I just updated my angular cli to version 6.0.0 
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDlWZ.jpg)

and noticed some errors after checking the version of angular cli.
When i'm trying to create a project using "ng-new my-app"(without quote) it gives me this error 
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNp8J.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct command name. Use:

```
ng new my-app
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but i tried that too still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed **Angular CLI globally**:

```
 npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Then the command `ng new` will be recognized in your shell.

Comment: i reinstalled my angular cli using that command but when creating a project the error still shows like on the second screenshot, i just noticed the @angular-devkit/architect <error> and @schematics/update <error> when checking the angular cli version using (ng -v) wondering if this could be the cause of the errors

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed the problem on the first screenshot, i updated my angular cli to version 6.0.1 using cmd, i was using git bash for updating my angular cli before, I think other modules was not installed globally that is why i received that error when checking the angular version.

[Finally no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv1jj.jpg)

On the second screenshot i don't know why i could not still create a project and received that error on desktop and users folder, but i could successfully create a project in other locations like drive D:\ or E:\ using ng new command.